# How to configure firefox built-in pdf viewer

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

I want to configure my `pdf.js` in Firefox.

Specifically, I want to set the default zoom from auto to something else, say 150%.

I found a `pdfjs.database` in `about:config`, which has a `"zoom":"auto"` in that table. I changed `auto` to `150%` but nothing happened when I opened a pdf.

It didn't crash and still opened pdf in auto zooming. Is it possible to configure `pdf.js` for this?

Comment: What's wrong with auto? There is more than one zoom value. Try changing them all to your own setting. Don't use percent, try a fixed value like "150".

Answer (score 24):

Mozilla have now implemented a default zoom setting, although it's only available through `about:config`.

You can change the `pdfjs.defaultZoomValue` in `about:config` to change the default zoom.

Set it to a number for a number (no percent sign) for a given default percent zoom.

Other possible values are page-width, page-height, page-fit and auto.

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/3850

Comment: Thanks a lot, `page-width` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Firefox just became my default pdf viewer, it has tabs, it releases the file while open (so I can generate it again with gnuplot), it updates it with F5.... I love Firefox!

Comment: I come back to this answer every few years with each new computer I get.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the `pdfjs.database` you found is actually a list of previously opened pdfs and their saved pdf view settings including last read page number and zoom level as well as a couple of other view settings.

On my machine this is a patial display of some of the contents of that key.

```
{"files":   [{"fingerprint":"7a798210f6814668a779da60662f2c6d","exists":true,"page":4,"zoom":"auto","scrollLeft":0,"scrollTop":617},  
{"fingerprint":"604c4e776174cb1f9b3f835f566827","exists":true,"page":2,"zoom":"150","scrollLeft":612,"scrollTop":792},  
{"fingerprint":"fb6578d44ae9f8f346bd67d57a2d8","exists":true,"page":1,"zoom":"auto","scrollLeft":0,"scrollTop":792}]}
```

Opening a new pdf and changing the view setting simply added a new item to the end of the list.

While changing the `Zoom` to `150` on all those items will affect documents you have already opened I do not believe you can set this up for new pdfs.

It appears this feature is known [but not being actively worked on](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1624). Also see [this drupal page](https://drupal.org/node/1679076).

[Source Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pdfjs+default+zoom)

Comment: +1, won't even affect the viewed items probably, I tried and could not get the change to persist. As soon as I closed the `about:config` tab or restarted `firefox` zoom went back to `auto`.